# What's the transpose complexity Big O in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, big-o, transpose, code-complexity

If i have the following two scenarios:

First scenario:

```
a = [1 2 3 4]
b = a'  %what's the Big O complexity here for transposing the "a" 1D array.
```

Second scenario:

```
a = [ [1 2 3 4] ; [5 6 7 8] ; [9 10 11 12]]
b = a'  %what's the Big O complexity here for transposing the "a" 2D array.
```

Comment: My gut tells me the first case is almost free, since the linear indices do not change (it's like `reshape()` in that aspect). The second one will be heavier, since it involves actual moving of elements in the RAM to be contiguous, but I wouldn't know by how much. Also note that you are using a **complex** transpose. `.'` is the regular transpose. Complex transposing will be even heavier than a normal transpose, even for non-complex arrays due to the check for complexicity.

Comment: O(1) and O(n) respectively.

Comment: @Adriaan arrays in MATLAB that have all real elements nearly always end up knowing this up-front (`isreal` is a per-array query based on the storage layout, not per-element), so `'` on a real array should usually be the same as `.'`.

Comment: `(c)transpose` on `full` arrays is pretty simple memory shuffling, so one would hope it ought to be trivial compared to whatever the rest of your program is doing. `sparse` arrays are harder...

Comment: Oh yeah, I totally forgot about sparse arrays. But at least OP's code is clearly using full (non-sparse) arrays. :) Any sparse array re-shuffling/re-indexing operation still has to be O(n) though, right, because it doesn't depend on any of the values contained in the array elements? (Where n is the total number of elements, not just the number of non-zero elements. Or is that the wrong approach?)

Answer (score 0):

O(1) and O(n) respectively, but these operations are so simple that Big-O notation probably isn't even appropriate.

```
a = [1 2 3 4]
b = a'
```

This is O(1), and is super fast. Matlab doesn't even rearrange (or even copy!) the actual data values in memory; it just copies the `mxArray` header and rewrites its dimensions array to indicate that the vector is laid out as 4-by-1 instead of 1-by-4.

```
a = [ [1 2 3 4] ; [5 6 7 8] ; [9 10 11 12]]
b = a'
```

For real (non-complex) values, this is O(n). It just creates a new array in memory and copies the old array's values into it, shuffling their order using an easily-computed array index mapping algorithm (which is just like two or three multiplies per element).

But: Both of these are trivial operations; you generally wouldn't even bother using Big-O notation to talk about them. The system-specific mechanics of array copying in memory and overhead of Matlab `mxArray` internals are much more important to their performance than the "algorithm" used to compute their results. Algorithm analysis terms are probably not the right level to be examining/discussing these operations at.

Note: This may not apply if you set up `a` and `b` to be sparse arrays instead of regular "full" arrays. They use a different data structure, and more processing has to happen to rearrange their elements. I'm pretty sure it'd still be O(n) for both of them, but that doesn't reflect the actual relative performance difference between them. But that's a broader question.

Comment: There is no reason that big O notation cannot or should not be used to analyse simple operations. On the contrary, we need to know the complexity of simple operations in order to derive the complexity of algorithms which use those operations.

Comment: The reason in this case is that big O analysis disregards any constant factors or coefficients involved. In a language like Matlab, those factors may be very significant: due to the difference between user-level M-code operations and built-in operations, and multithreading, two operations with the same big-O complexity may have very different run times in practice. So if the question is "How fast do these Matlab operations run, compared to each other or to other common operations?", you may have to look at things besides big-O to understand their relative performance.

Comment: That is true for all operations, whether or not they are simple.